# Why GiveWP donation form not loading in?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins, display

I am making a donation website, and I'm trying to test, how this plugin works.

I made a test donation form and added to a test page.

The main problem is, the form is trying to load in, and after 2-3 seconds a blank page loading in.

What Am I missing?

Link here: [test page](https://www.mindengyermeklakjonjol.hu/?page_id=108)

Thank you!

I tried every possible sollutions, but didn't work for me!

Comment: If you haven't done so already, try posting your question on [GiveWP's support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/give/). You'll get better chances at getting a proper answer there than over here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.